# Why is "no new release" found after I'm told its available?

Tags: 11.04, upgrade

```
New release 'oneiric' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

2222222-desktop:~$ do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new ubuntu release
No new release found
```

why does it say there is an upgrade then says it does not find it?

I have been slowly upgrading from 9x to 11.04. I had some issues along the way but nothing google could not help me with. Now this has me stuck.

I have tried

```
sudo apt-get update
```

this worked so it was not the issue I had before where my keys were invalid.

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

after that did nothing.

`sudo do-release-upgrade`  returned with "no upgrade found"

`do-release-upgrade -d.` did the trick. I should have tried it since I did come across the -d tag in researching this. I had thought since the terminal itself knew there was an update available, it should find it. Thank you all for helping.

Comment: I have been slowly updating this computer from 9.something researching and learning all the way, but can't find out how to get around this... so far.

Comment: I checked  /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades

Prompt=normal   I tried sudo apt-get update with normal results. I then did sudo apt-get upgrade -- nothing to upgrade. I tried do-release-upgrade too.

Comment: Which Ubuntu are you trying to upgrade from?

Comment: can anybody tell me what the Lord is trying to say? I am guilty of not reading btw. Will look for them. Release notes for 11.10 or 12?

Comment: disregard my previous comment.  Read my new one and respond.

Comment: derek@derek-desktop:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 11.04
Release:        11.04
Codename:       natty

Comment: why is it that I can't put in returns in comment boxes? or use the code button? Sorry derailement

Comment: @Jonathan - You can edit your original question to include new information.

Comment: @Jonathan mark any answer that helped you with an upvote if you can, and if you can't, you can still accept the answer that helped..  Hit the check mark next to the answer that helped to accept it

Answer (score 1):

> do-release-upgrade

should be prefixed with sudo

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

and you may want to run the following command first

```
sudo apt-get update
```

although if you have been upgrading from 9.xx then you probably know that anyway,

so I apologise for stating the obvious if that is the case.   :o)

Comment: yep yep yep, I have forgotten sudo often enough when trying to do something. I forgot to add it when I commented. :)

Answer (score 0):

**From Natty to Oneiric**
[Oneiric Release Notes - Upgrading](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OneiricOcelot/ReleaseNotes#Upgrading)
Focus on the "Upgrading from 11.04" section.

> To upgrade from Ubuntu 11.04 on a desktop system, press Alt+F2 and type in `update-manager -d` into the command box. Update Manager should open up and display following message: "New distribution release '11.10' is available. Click Upgrade and follow the on-screen instructions".
>
> To upgrade from Ubuntu 11.04 on a server system, follow the steps listed below:
>   Step 1: Install the update-manager-core package (if it is not already installed).
>   Step 2: Use following command: `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` to launch the upgrade
>   tool.
>   Step 3: Follow the on-screen instructions. Note that the server upgrade is now more robust and will utilize GNU screen and automatically re-attach in case of dropped connection problems, for example.

---

**Precise**
[Precise Release Notes - Desktop - Upgrading](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#Upgrading)
[Precise Release Notes - Server/CLI - Upgrading](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuServer#Upgrade)

Using CLI and `do-release-upgrade`:

**You will need to upgrade to Oneiric (11.10) first before you can upgrade to Precise.**

> **From 11.10 to 12.04**
>   To upgrade from Ubuntu 11.10 on a server system, follow the steps listed below:
>   1.Install the update-manager-core package (if it is not already installed).
>   2.Run sudo do-release-upgrade to launch the upgrade tool.
>   3.Follow the on-screen instructions. Note that the server upgrade is now more robust and will utilize GNU screen and automatically re-attach in case of dropped connection problems, for example.
>
> **From 10.04 to 12.04**
>   ([see the release notes for Server/CLI](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuServer#Upgrade))

Comment: That command will try and update to the latest development release - 12.10 and not 12.04?.

  man do-release-upgrade -d, --devel-release
              Check if upgrading to the latest devel release is possible

Comment: @FernhillLinuxProject see the release notes for Oneiric, i've linked them.  The release notes explain how to upgrade to different releases.  If he's on 11.04 as he stated, he'll need to do incremental upgrades (see Oneiric release notes first)

Comment: As stated he is using 11.04 and trying to upgrade to 11.10. sudo do-release-upgrade will incrementally upgrade you to the next version, in this case 11.10. This is not working in this case - not sure why, but release notes on upgrading 11.10 to 12.04 will not help much, neither will sudo do-release-upgrade -d. I am curious what could be causing the problem though - any suggestions?

Comment: Note because of copying issues where formatting explodes here, I've not included the majority of the stuff for Precise.  Please refer to the release notes as needed, using Desktop release notes for GUI, and Server/CLI for CLI upgrading.

Comment: That seemed to do something. I thought I was taking care of that by editing my /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades so that the Prompt=normal. I had come across the -d  tag before but for some reason didn't try it. Thank you.

Comment: @Fernhill perhaps you should read the release notes as well for Upgrading to Oneiric, and seeing my most-recently edited response/answer.

Comment: @Jonathan no problem, from the IRC support rooms, we actually point people to the release notes when they're using `do-release-upgrade` when people ask why they need to add `-d`, because depending on where you're coming from `do-release-upgrade` won't operate as you'd expect it to. I strongly recommend reading the release notes for Upgrading (you too, Fernhill), as that explains upgrading between versions.

Comment: @Fernhill also, half of your comments here are no longer valid, when I originally wrote this he didnt say he was on 11.04, so...  </critical review of comments>