# upgrade from 12.10 to 13.x - says "no new release found"

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, updates

I'd like to upgrade from 12.10 to 13.10, even if that means upgrading to 13.04 first

```
dell@dell:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.10
Release:    12.10
Codename:   quantal
dell@dell:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
[sudo] password for dell: 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
dell@dell:~$
```

I followed instructions from http://linuxg.net/yet-another-way-to-upgrade-update-from-ubuntu-12-10-to-ubuntu-13-04/, and [upgrade ubuntu 12.04 to 13](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310824/upgrade-ubuntu-12-04-to-13), and http://linuxg.net/update-from-ubuntu-12-10-to-ubuntu-13-04-by-terminal/, and [Why is "no new release" found after I'm told its available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160468/why-is-no-new-release-found-after-im-told-its-available), and similar googles. they all tell pretty much the same thing, which I have *tried*. Software updater continues to say "The software on this computer is up to date". I have *never* been notified that 13.x is available.

Comment: try doing sudo apt-get update and upgrade before do-release-upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the terminal to insert the following commands:

Upgrading to the new version:

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

(`-d` will let you see new versions)

After the upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade`
```

Hope it helped you out.

Comment: had already tried `sudo do-release-upgrade -c` and also `-f`; did a power cycle between update-manager-core (which *was* already installed) and this one kicked it off. Of course, about 3 hours into the process my wife turned off the laptop so I got stuck in a 'power failure during installation' type error. which http://askubuntu.com/a/40058/99436 resolved (plus a `sudo fsck -f`). after that, `dpkg --configure -d` came to the rescue. All happily working again! Cheers for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you check and ensure that "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version" is set correctly.

1. Open *Software Sources*.
2. In the "Updates" tab, ensure that "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version" is set to "For any new version".
3. Then retry:

   ```
   do-release-upgrade
   ```

Comment: yep, it was. this was mentioned by some of the articles I'd linked too. I was frustated that it didn't show me, even though that's what it was supposed to do.